# Does $d(x,y) = \lvert N(x) - N(y)\rvert$ satisfy the triangular inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $N(x)$ be the norm of the vector $X$ and efine

$$d(x,y) = |N(x) - N(y)|$$

I want to prove that $d(x,y)$ satisfies the triangular inequality. Here is my attempt:

$$|N(x) - N(y)| \leq |N(x)| + |N(y)| = $$
$$=|\left[N(x)-N(z)\right] + N(z)| + |\left[N(y)-N(z)\right] + N(z)| \leq $$
$$ \leq |N(x)-N(z)| + |N(z)| + |N(y)-N(z)| + |N(z)| \leq $$
$$ \leq d(x,z) + d(y,z) + 2|N(z)| \leq d(x,z) + d(y,z).$$

Is this right?

**Additions**
Ok, the last line is wrong. Then, can I prove that $d$ satisfies the triangular inequality???

**Remark**
I don't want to prove that $d$ is a metric!

Comment: I don't like the last line!

Comment: Correct until the last inequality (which seems wrong unless $|N(z)|=0$...).

Comment: I don't want to prove that $d$ is a metric.

Comment: @brick,Milly thanks, so what I can do to prove that? or I can't prove that?

Comment: @the_candyman Hey, you already have an answer. Check and approve it.

Comment: @brick. Ok, I'll approve... Which one?

Comment: @the_candyman The only one below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine that you want to show that:

*If $N :X\to\mathbb R$ is $1-1$, then $d(x,y)=\lvert N(x)-N(y)\rvert$ is a metric.*

Clearly, the only property which needs checking is the triangular inequality.

We have that
$$
d(x,z)=\lvert N(x)-N(z)\rvert\le\lvert N(x)-N(y)\rvert+\lvert N(y)-N(z)\rvert=d(x,y)+d(y,z).
$$

Note. The fact that $N$ is 1-1 guarantees that $d(x,y)>0$, if $x\ne 0$.

Comment: It is a metric iff $N$ is 1-1! - I have mentioned it!

Comment: I don't want to prove that $d$ is metric